# Dealing with warnings when running SAS in batch

Tags: makefile, sas

I like to use Makefiles so I frequently run SAS programs in batch from the command line. SAS will return a non-zero status of 1 if it encounters any warnings, and a non-zero status of 2 or greater if there is an error.

This means the make errors out even if there are only warnings. I can force the Makefile to ignore non-zero statuses, but then it also ignores actual errors.

How would I write a Makefile such that it errors out if I get a non-zero status of 2 or greater, but continues for a non-zero status of 1?

ex:

```
myOutput.sas7bdat: myProgram.sas
   "path/to/sas.exe" $<
## ignore errors
myOutput.sas7bdat: myProgram.sas
   -"path/to/sas.exe" $<
```

Comment: Did you try creating your own script that wraps the SAS call and converts the return code to 0/1 values?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `.ONESHELL` if your version of make supports it (4.0+ for windows)

```
.ONESHELL:
myOutput.sas7bdat: myProgram.sas
    "path/to/sas.exe" $<
    if %ERRORLEVEL% gtr 1 exit /b 1
```

Or you can wrap those two lines into a batch file (replacing `$<` with `%1` in the file)

```
myOutput.sas7bdat: myProgram.sas
    whatever.cmd $<
```